# the union of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space and $X = A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3}$ s.th. $A_{1},A_{2}$ and $A_{3}$ are pairwise disjoint closed subsets of $X.$ Let $f_{i}:A_{i}\rightarrow B_{i}$ where $B_{i}$ is a subset of $X$ and $i =1,2,3.$ 
Define $f:X \rightarrow X$ by $f = \vee f_{i}$. Show that if each $f_{i}$ is continuous, then so is $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A_1 = X \setminus (A_2 \cup A_3)$ etc, the closedness of the $A_i$ tells us that they are also open. Given any open set $U \subset X$, we have $$f^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_i f_i^{-1}(U).$$ By the continuity of $f_i$ we know $f_i^{-1}(U)$ is open in the subspace topology of $A_i \subset X$, which means $f_i^{-1}(U) = V \cap A_i$ for some open $V$. The openness of $A_i$ then implies that $f_i^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, so $f^{-1}(U)$ is a union of open sets and therefore open.